# R spread() Error with unknown column name

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm using `spread()` function for the data frame with fields:

```
Company | FoundYear | AmountTotal |Industry
```

when I run the `spread` command against that data frame, it says an error for the column, which does not even exist in my data frame.

```
spread(mydata, key = FoundYear, value = AmountTotal)

Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `Startup` is unknown
```

Any help about the idea why this anomaly might be happening is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? Part of your data.frame so we can produce the same error. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)` solved, but still confused why the error throw the fieldname which is not in the data frame.